# Changing the width of boxes in colorbar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, colorbar

I have a really simple color bar (for which I have removed the legend). My data is structured so there are much more rows than columns. I'd like to make each box wider to make to aspect ratio of width to height closer to 1:1, but haven't found anything in the property documentation that would do this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

data = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=[2000,20])


cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm)
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: like `cax = ax.imshow(data, interpolation='nearest', cmap=cm.coolwarm, aspect='auto')`?

Comment: @cel ahhh, perfect! I was trying to look into setting a pixel dimension so was looking in the wrong area!